# Method load fails in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-3

I was using `codeigniter 2.2.1`. And now `codeigniter 3` released. I just tried it and ended up with error.

When I try to load method as in `codeigniter2.x`, it shows

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: Demo
```

where `Demo` is my method file.

**Controller - welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('demo');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = $this -> demo ->check();
        print_r($data);
    }

}
```

**Model - demo.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Demo extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

}
```

I can't figure-out what is wrong with this code. Please help. Thank you in advance..

**Edit:-** This is works well in my wamp machine. But I am checking it now in another local machine where my institute host the websites. There it is not working

Comment: is your model file Demo.php or demo.php, Also best to auto load data base remove this $this->load->database(); make sure you have put your database info on database.php before auto load it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a small issue. I changed model name from `demo.php` to `Demo.php`. And it works...

Comment: As of CI3, libraries, drivers, controllers and models should all have their first character capitalized, so make sure you update all file names accordingly. Also check out the [2.2 to 3.0 upgrade guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html).

Comment: Thanks to @mustang83 for their comment